# How to force Windows 10 to go to sleep after 30 minutes?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, sleep

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Video Wake Lock
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Video Wake Lock

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] Conexant SmartAudio HD (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5111&SUBSYS_17AA505C&REV_1001\4&1358c543&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
WebRTC has active PeerConnections

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.
```

Is there a way to make Windows 10 to go to sleep. I think Chrome somehow keeps it alive and doesn't let the desktop to go to sleep.

Comment: Chrome is playing a video from the Internet. An Internet connection cannot sleep.

Comment: @harrymc isn’t it possible to force it?

Comment: No, this will only disconnect it. A connection cannot be kept open indefinitely while the computer is in sleep state.

Comment: @harrymc how comes the kernel can’t force the computer to go to sleep?

Comment: It can, but Chrome has indicated to Windows that it shouldn't sleep.

Answer (score 4):

Overriding Chrome's ability to keep the system awake might help. Try using this command (from an admin command prompt):

`powercfg /requestsoverride process chrome.exe awaymode display system`

The `awaymode`, `display` and `system` cover all the types of requests the process can make to prevent sleep.

You can remove this override with:

`powercfg /requestsoverride process chrome.exe`

And lastly, you can list the current overrides with:

`powercfg /requestsoverride`